# Formatting a json file to add another field

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed, jq

I have a json file with the format given below.I want to modify the file so as to add another key-value pair to it. The key should be `url` and the value should be `www.mywebsite.co.nz` extracted from the message given below. What is the easiset way to do this?

```
{"  
Timestamp":"Mon Mar 16 21:37:22 EDT 2015","Event":"Reporting  Time","Message":"load for http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:1xxxx/operations&proxy=www.mywebsite.co.nz&send=https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/operations?event took 9426 ms (X Time: 306 ms, Y Time: 1923 ms)
StatusCode: Unknown<br>Cookies: nzh_weatherlocation=12; dax_ppv=11|NZH:home|NZH:home|NZH:home|9|undefined; _ga=GA1.4.1415798036.1426208630; _gat=1<br>Links: 225<br>Images: 24<br>Forms: 10<br>Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/41.0.2272.76 Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36<br>CPUs: 2<br>Language: en-GB","UserInfo":"Reporting Time"}
```

Comment: Add `,"url":"www.mywebsite.co.nz"` before the ending `}`? Am I missing something here?

Comment: :) I know that.I have a large set of files to be processed. I can't do it manually.I want to automate it by some means

Comment: Why not use a language like PHP or Python that has built-in JSON read/write capabilities?

Comment: I could use python.Not very familiar though

Comment: In PHP it'd be simply `$content = file_get_contents('path.json'); $json = json_decode($content); $json->url = 'www.mywebsite.co.nz'; $content = json_encode($content); file_put_contents('path.json', $content);`

Comment: www.mywebsite.co.nz is just an example.It could very well be www.amazon.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a combination of `jq` and `sed`:

```
jq ".url = \"$(jq '.Message' input.json | sed 's/.*proxy=\([^&]*\).*/\1/')\"" input.json > output.json
```

This consists of three steps:

```
jq '.Message' input.json
```

extracts the message part from the input JSON,

```
sed 's/.*proxy=\([^&]*\).*/\1/'
```

extracts the domain from the message, and

```
jq ".url = \"domainname\"" input.json > output.json
```

sets the `.url` attribute of the input json to the extracted domain name, writing the result to `output.json`.

I feel compelled to point out, by the way, that a domain name by itself is not technically a URL, so you may want to rethink that attribute name.

Comment: "www.mywebsite.co.nz" is just an example. The point is it has to be extracted from "Message". It could very well be www.amazon.com

Comment: Nice. You might consider `grep -oP '(?<=proxy=).*?(?=&)'` in place of sed

Answer (score 1):

For `perl` users, using [ojo](https://metacpan.org/pod/ojo):

```
perl -Mojo -E '$j=j(b("input.file")->slurp);if($j->{Message}=~m/proxy=(.*?)&/){$j->{url}=$1;say j($j)}'
```

decomposed:

- `b()->slurp` - reads the `input.file`
- `j()` - converts the json to perl data
- if the `Message` contains "proxy=site&" - get the site
- add to the data the `url => site`
- `j()` convert to json string
- and print it.